# Where does the data go that a user enters in an HTML text field?

Tags: html

Im very confused and am not sure what to type into google to find out how to receive data that a user enters in an HTML text field. So that is why I am asking this question here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can know which data has been entered with php, javascript, ajax,...

Your HTML text field:

```
<form action="process.php" name="myForm" id="idForm">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<!-- if you want to take it with javascript add that-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</script>
```

Get it with PHP:
process.php looks like that:

```
<?php
// Verify $_POST['name'] exist
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{

//verify $_POST['name'] is not empty

   if(!empty($_POST['name']))
   {
     echo $_POST['name'];
   }

}

?>
```

Get it with Javascript (This can able you not to refresh the page):
test.js:

```
var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
```